# Fortran: read multiple spaces file

Tags: fortran, fortran90

I try to read a file as such (the numbers here are equal just to have an idea of the format of the file):

```
0.7498000E-01 0.1046400E+00 0.4006199E-01 0.1978479E+01
0.7498000E-01 0.1046400E+00 0.4006199E-01 0.1978479E+01
0.7498000E-01 0.1046400E+00 0.4006199E-01 0.1978479E+01

0.7498000E-01 0.1046400E+00 0.4006199E-01 0.1978479E+01
0.7498000E-01 0.1046400E+00 0.4006199E-01 0.1978479E+01
0.7498000E-01 0.1046400E+00 0.4006199E-01 0.1978479E+01

0.7498000E-01 0.1046400E+00 0.4006199E-01 0.1978479E+01
0.7498000E-01 0.1046400E+00 0.4006199E-01 0.1978479E+01
0.7498000E-01 0.1046400E+00 0.4006199E-01 0.1978479E+01
```

My code is the follow one:

### CASE 1

```
program selection
implicit none
    integer :: i,n,s,j  
    REAL*8,allocatable:: dum1(:),dum2(:),dum3(:),dum4(:)

open(10,file='file.txt')
    n=0
    DO
      READ(10,*,END=100)          
      n=n+1
    END DO

 100     continue
    rewind(10)
allocate(dum1(n),dum2(n),dum3(n)dum4(n))

s=0
    do s=1, n
      read(10,*) dum1(s),dum2(s),dum3(s),dum4(s)
    end do

end program selection
```

The problem are the spaces between two different set of data that give to me `forrtl: severe (24): end-of-file during read` during the reading.

So I solve this problem just saying to the code how many lines the file has, and I modify the code as such:

### CASE 2

```
program selection
implicit none
    integer :: i,n,s,j  
    REAL*8,allocatable:: dum1(:),dum2(:),dum3(:),dum4(:)

open(10,file='file.txt')
n = 9 ! number of rows in the particular file in this example

allocate(dum1(n),dum2(n),dum3(n)dum4(n))

s=0
    do s=1, n
      read(10,*) dum1(s),dum2(s),dum3(s),dum4(s)
    end do

end program selection
```

My question is: is there some way to modify the iterative process in CASE 1 such as I can automatically read empty lines, too?

Answer (score 1):

A minimal change to count non-empty lines. More checking can be added if desirable or necessary.

```
    character(max_line_length) :: line
    open(10,file='file.txt')

    n=0
    DO
      read(10,'(a)',end=100) line
      if (len_trim(line)>0) n = n + 1
    END DO

 100     continue
```

Normally, I prefer to stop counting on any end-of-file condition or error-condition using `iostat=`)

```
    character(max_line_length) :: line
    integer :: ie
    open(10,file='file.txt')

    n=0
    DO
      read(10,'(a)',iostat=ie) line
      if (ie/=0) exit
      if (len_trim(line)>0) n = n + 1
    END DO
```